# ActiveRecord find where many dates don't overlap with many other dates (Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

What I'm trying to do is pretty complicated, but bear with me. I am using Rails, ActiveRecord, Postgres.

Events **have many** locations and **have many** start and end times. Users can assign themselves to an event.

A User can only be in one place at a time. So, on the "assign yourself to an event page", I need to only show the Events that don't have overlapping times with the User's already assigned events.

I know that you can do this with a join but I can't figure out how.

Models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  has_many :event_times
  has_many :assignments
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :event_times
end

class EventTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :event
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

This sums up what I'm trying to do. I know it's terrible.

```
user_events = Assignment.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:event_id)
blocked_event_times = EventTime.where(event_id: user_events)

blocked_query_string = ""

blocked_event_times.each do |bt|
  blocked_query_string += "NOT( event_times.start <= '#{bt.end}'::timestamp AND event_times.end >= '#{bt.start}'::timestamp ) AND "
end
blocked_query_string += "1=1"


return Event.includes(:event_times).where(blocked_query_string).references(:event_times)
```

Am I on the right track thinking I should do something like (pseudocode):

```
@acceptable_times = EventTime.all LEFT JOIN user's_assigned_event_times
```

and then get the Events where all of the event's times are present in @acceptable_times

Comment: Don't use `end` as the name of column in ActiveRecord. `end` is a reserved word in Ruby - if you try to call it without the explicit subject you get a syntax error. That is a pretty big violation of the [principle of least suprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Instead you may want to follow the convention used by timestamps: `ends_at`, `starts_at`.

Comment: Also I would consider storing the start and end times on the events table to cut down on the level of complication.

Comment: The thing is, an event can have many start and end times. Thanks for the heads up on the reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of the data format or how the EventTime model is working so here is another solution based on an `Assignment` having a `start_time` and `end_time` and an event having `start_time` and `end_time`.

I guess you could pass in an instance of `EventTime` rather than `Event` taking my example below.

```
def overlaps_existing_commitment?(event)
  current_user.assignments.where("assignments.start_time < ? AND assignments.end_time > ?, event.start_time, event.end_time).any?
end
```

So was thinking you could loop through the events:

```
events_to_render = []

@events.each do |event|
  unless overlaps_existing_commitment?(event)
    events_to_render << event
  end
end
```

You can then use the `events_to_render` array in your view.

I am sure there are many better ways, but hopefully provides some inspiration to get to a solution you are happy with!

---

A couple of others things:

- The more I look at it, the more I am convinced that the EventTime model is not needed. And it will make life alot easier for you by adding `start_time` and `end_time` attributes to the other models.
- Make use of the '?' in your SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, one event can have many start and end times. (eg. multi-day event in the morning)

I actually did something similar as my first attempt, looping through the each event. But the performance of that is O(N+1).